# VB.net | Finding duplicates in a multidimensional array

Tags: vb.net, multidimensional-array

I have two forms: **Act9.vb** and **List.vb**. The code in both forms is below. I'm using vb.net "4.7.2" in visual studio.
I have been very frustrated with this program for a while now. For some reason the program only checks new clients against the first and second clients already in the list. For example, if the following entries are in the list:

```
╔═════════╦═════════════╗
║ ClientA ║ 32423223343 ║
╠═════════╬═════════════╣
║ ClientB ║ 23422322343 ║
╠═════════╬═════════════╣
║ ClientC ║ 23423423423 ║
╠═════════╬═════════════╣
║ ClientD ║ 43533453333 ║
╠═════════╩═════════════╣
║ etc...                ║
╚═══════════════════════╝
```

Then if I try to modify ClientA or ClientB (pressing btnModify and then typing "ClientA"/"ClientB" in the inputbox), then it works, but if I try the same with ClientC, D, E, etc. it doesn't. I get this message: "This client doesn't exist. Please try again."
Same thing with adding new clients: it won't let me add ClientA or B twice, but if I try to add Client C more then once it doesn't realize that it's already in the multidimensional array and let's me add it a second time.

If someone knows anything that can help, please share.
Thanks in advance!

```
Public Class Act9
    Public Clients(1, 1) As String
    Public size As Integer = 0

    Sub Add()
        Dim tempClient As String
        Dim tempTel As String

        tempClient = InputBox("Please enter the clients name :", "Name")

        If Duplicate(tempClient) Then
            MsgBox("This client already exists")

        Else
            tempTel = InputBox("Please enter the client's phone number:", "Phone number")

            Clients(0, size) = tempClient
            Clients(1, size) = tempTel

            size += 1
            ReDim Preserve Clients(1, size)
        End If
    End Sub

    Function Duplicate(ByVal tempClient As String) As Boolean
        Dim output As Boolean = False
        For i As Integer = LBound(Clients) To UBound(Clients)
            If Clients(0, i) = tempClient Then
                output = True
            End If
        Next
        Return output
    End Function

    Private Sub BtnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        Add()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnShow_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnShow.Click
        List.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnErase_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnErase.Click
        ReDim Clients(1, size)
        List.lstClients.Items.Clear()
        size = 0
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnModify_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnModify.Click
        modify()
    End Sub

    Sub modify(Optional who As String = Nothing)
        Dim change As Boolean = False

        If who = Nothing Then who = InputBox("Please enter the name of the client you wish to modify:", "Modify")

        For i As Integer = LBound(Clients) To UBound(Clients)
            If Clients(0, i) = who Then
                Clients(0, i) = InputBox("Please enter the new name for the client:", "Name")
                Clients(1, i) = InputBox("Please enter the new phone number for the client", "Phone number")
                change = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If change = False Then MsgBox("This client doesn't exist. Please try again.")
    End Sub
End Class
```

```
Public Class List
    Private Sub List_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        lstClients.Items.Clear()

        For i As Integer = 0 To Act9.size - 1
            lstClients.Items.Add(Act9.Clients(0, i) & vbTab & Act9.Clients(1, i))
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Quite honestly a multidimensional array is a suboptimal structure to use for this sort of data. Consider a `Dictionary(Of String, String)`

Comment: I'd recommend setting a breakpoint and stepping through the code in the debugger.

Comment: @CaiusJard yeah, sadly. I'm not here trying to cheat, though. I'm just stuck and want to see if someone can spot the issue or give some good advice.

Comment: @Craig Thank you, thank you. This probably sounds stupid but I didn't know how to do that. I looked it up and tried it. It helped me find and fix the problem in mere minutes. That's a really useful tool! I don't know how to express my gratitude for how much time this will save me. Thanks again. =)

Comment: I asked if it was homework chiefly because it alters the advice given; you probably have parameters like "must use a multidimensional array" which means that no matter how much we implore you to change it (because they're mostly a crap way of storing anything and I've never in my professional life used them, not even once, since leaving academia) you can't.

Comment: I'd recommend calling your method IsDuplicate because it returns a Boolean. Calling it Duplicate implies that the object passed in will be duplicated

Answer (score 0):

@Craig Told me to use breakpoints which are the perfect tools for this. I'm very grateful for the advice.

Here is how I ended up getting it to work properly:

I replaced LBound and Ubound with my variable "size" (which was already taking care of counting the size of my multidimensional array).

The For loop in "Duplicate" becomes:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To size
            If Clients(0, i) = tempClient Then
                output = True
            End If
        Next
```

The one in "Modify becomes:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To size
            If Clients(0, i) = who Then
                Clients(0, i) = InputBox("Please enter the new name for the client:", "Name")
                Clients(1, i) = InputBox("Please enter the new phone number for the client", "Phone number")
                change = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your original code didn't work out is because you LBound/UBound on the first dimension but your array extends on the second dimension. The first dimension is only ever 0 to 1 so you only ever checked the second dimension indexes 0 and 1 (the first two items) for the name:

```
 For i As Integer = LBound(Clients) To UBound(Clients)
```

If you use

```
 LBound(Clients, 2) to UBound(Clients, 2)
```

It will get the upper limit of the second dimension rather than the first. UBound uses 1-based indexing whereas VB uses 0 based. If you want the same thing in 0 based you can use

```
Array.GetUpperBound(Clients, 1)
```

to find the limit of the second dimension

Other tips:

- your modify method makes the same bounding mistake
- if this were programming 201 you'd probably be using a List(Of Client), Client being a class having a pair of string properties for name and tel, and an overridden equals method that compares the name of an incoming Client, so that list.Contains can be used to prevent duplicates. Eventually you'd probably override GetHashCode too and use a HashSet(Of Client). And this whole thing would actually be a lot easier. Multidimensional arrays are usually a poor storage solution for.. well.. everything
- your `size` variable is public; it should have a capital s
- your modify method is a method; it should have a capital M. All methods in .net have capital initial letters
- maybe btnErase should set the size before it redims
- your duplicate method checks every item in the array. It carries on checking even if it already found a duplicate item. You can skip the part where you create a Boolean and just straight Return True inside the If; your keys are always in the last place you look because you stop looking when you find them :)
- perhaps if you implement a FindIndex method that takes a name and returns the index of where that person is, or -1 if it didn't find them then you can use it for both IsDuplicate (call findindex and return true if the result is greater than -1) and for Modify (find the index of the person and change them or put a message Not Found if -1 comes bac). This means you can have just one method that searches the array and you use it twice. It means you Don't Repeat Yourself - a software engineering principle we try to stick to. At the moment your duplicate and modify methods both have the same loop (with the same bug)

Comment: Thank you for the help. That's all great advice. 
I didn't have the choice to use something other than a multidimensional array as that was part of the assignment. I do realise that it's not a very good storage method.
Thanks again for your help.